# How to avoid overriding targets, or suppress the warning

Tags: makefile, overriding, gnu-make, target

I want to create a makefile to be included in others, kind of as a "library", let's call it library.mak:

```
TARGET_FILES = a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
SRC_FOLDER = somewhere/else
.PHONY: all
all:
    for target in ${TARGET_FILES} ; do \
        echo -e "\nMaking $${target}:" ;\
        ${MAKE} ${MFLAGS} --no-print-directory $${target} ;\
    done

.PHONY: ${TARGET_FILES}
${TARGET_FILES}:
    cp  ${SRC_FOLDER}/$@  $@
```

The two rules are there to make all, as well as one specific target, respectively; using a default rule (which is the purpose of library.mak).

In my "user makefile" called Makefile, I want to then do this:

```
include library.mak

# special handling of c.txt
c.txt:
    grep -v 'all except this' ${SRC_FOLDER}/$@ > $@
```

As you can see, the user wants to be able to override the behaviour for some special cases.  While this works, it always greets the user with the dreaded `warning: overriding recipe for target` and `warning: ignoring old commands for target` messages, even though the behaviour is as intended.

So here's the question: Can this be done in a different way that avoids these warnings, or is there a means to suppress them?

Answer (score 1):

The warning says you overwrite a recipe for an *explicit* rule. And this is really wrong. It makes sense to use a pattern rule instead, like: `%.txt: ${SRC_FOLDER}/%.txt`. Then it's ok to have some explicit rule (`c.txt: ${SRC_FOLDER}/c.txt)` overwriting a recipe. Of course, it's not 100% the same, but, I think that should not be a problem. Anyway, putting an explicit rule into a reusable file is a crime.

Next, you constantly use "phonies" and rules w/o prerequisites even when you definitely should have them. This is bad. You're trying to make "make" work as a non-branching shell script. That's not only inefficient but also is a misuse. Basically, make can be viewed as "shell extension" capable of "branching on file timestamps in a sophisticated way". If you don't need it, don't use make at all.

Next, I see absolutely no reason to go into recursive make. Whatever, you're going to do, I believe, you can do without it. And even if you really need recursion, then write simply `$(MAKE)`. `$(MFLAGS)` shoud not be used anymore (read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html)).

P.S. There's yet another (more flexible) option to define parameterized variables (macros). For example:

```
define nl :=


endef
define myrule.text
    $1: $2/$1
        @cp $$< $$@
endef
myrule = $(eval $(foreach foo$0,$1,$(call myrule.text,$(foo$0),$2)$(nl)))
...
# user makefile
# for everything except c.txt call predefined macro
$(call myrule,$(filter-out c.txt,$(TARGET_FILES)),$(SRC_FOLDER))
# for c.txt only
c.txt: $(SRC_FOLDER)/c.txt
    grep -v 'all except this' $< >$@
```

But as you see, it's a bit of a "cryptic" stuff, and I don't feel like recommending it for a beginner.

Comment: I couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you upon the kind word.